# PowerShell if/else Test-Path

Tags: powershell

For some reason the if/else clause is not working. It does create the directories but it doesn't execute the if part by saying 'Folder exists already'. It must be something super obvious I am not seeing as a noob. Thank you for your help.

```
Set-Location "\\domain.net\Target" 

$Folders = Import-Csv "C:\Temp\Test.csv" 

ForEach ($Folder in $Folders) { 

    if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $Folder -PathType Container)
    { 
    Write-Host "Folder exists already"
    } 
    else 
    {
    New-Item $Folder.Name -Type Directory 
    }
}
```

CSV-file content example:

```
Name
Folder1
Folder2
Folder3
Folder3\Folder1
```

**Solution** thanks to the help from the guys below:

```
#================= VARIABLES ==================================================
 $Target = "\\Temp\Target" 
 $InputF = "\\Temp\Downloads\Test.csv" 
#
# CSV-File format:
# Name
# Dir1
# Dir2
# Dir3\Subdir1

CLS
Write-Host "Folder creation`n"

#$Target = Read-Host "Provide the full UNC-Path where we need to create subfolders"
#$InputF = Read-Host "Provide the full UNC-Path & name of the CSV input file"

$Folders = Import-Csv $InputF 
Set-Location $Target

Write-Host "`nStarting folder creation:`n"

ForEach ($Folder in $Folders) { 

    if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $Folder.Name -PathType Container)
    { 
    Write-Host "-Exists: $Target\$($Folder.Name)" -ForegroundColor DarkGray
    } 
    else 
    {
    New-Item $Folder.Name -Type Directory  > $null
    Write-Host "-Created: $Target\$($Folder.Name)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need a sample of the csv to help you. The most likely problem is that set path equal to the row-object(`$folder`). A CSV has headers, so you need to access the property with the path.. Ex.

```
if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $Folder.Name -PathType Container)
```

**UPDATE:** Example updated with correct property name after the csv sample was provided.

Comment: CSV-File content added to initial post

Comment: use `$Folder.Name` in the if clause, as in `if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $Folder.Name -PathType Container)` to access the folder name

Comment: Yes, you are right. Changing the if clause to $Folder.Name fixed it. Thank you very much! :)